# Strange issues with Android AVD for API level 21 and up

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently updated Android Studio to version 1.5 from 1.02.  I had been running mainly API level 19 emulators and everything was fine.  Now I am trying to run emulators for Lollipop and Marshmallow.  I spent over an hour trying various API levels, and here is what I am seeing.

These were all run on an AMD Phenom II processor running Ubuntu 14.04 (with KVM enabled):

- API level 19 x86 - works fine
- API level 19 x86 Google API's - works fine
- API level 21 x86 - works fine
- API level 21 x86 Google API's - boots, but Google Play Services crashes
- API level 22 x86 - works fine
- API level 22 x86 Google API's - boots, but Google Play Services crashes
- API level 23 x86 - emulator does not boot (black screen)
- API level 23 x86 Google API's - emulator does not boot (black screen)

however

- API level 23 **arm** Google API's - seems to work, but is , as expected, painfully slow

Can anyone shed any light on what is going on here?

Comment: I have had nothing problems with the Google Play Services with the emulator for API 21-22. I have found my success even varied from computer to computer (both Macs).

Comment: for me,  things seem fine on the mac.  I installed Android Studio on my mac mini (purchased to learn iOS and swift), and everything seems to work fine on the mac mini